# How to chain exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception-handling, exception, logging

I have some function like:

```
void foo() { ... }


int main() {
  ...
  try {
    ...
    foo();
    ...
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Fatal error: e.what() << std::endl();
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

If an exception is thrown from `foo`, I'd like to know it. Also I want to know the reason of the original exception. I can split the code like this:

```
int main() {
  ... 
  try {
    ... 
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Fatal error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  try {
    foo();
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Fatal error (foo): " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  try {
    ... 
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Fatal error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

It doesn't look good. Instead, I can update `foo`:

```
void foo()
{
  try {
    ..
  } catch (const std::exception &) {
    std::cout << "Foo failed. The reason is:" << std::endl;
    throw;
  }
}
```

However, I do not like solution, too (maybe, because error logging is split).  What is the right way to raise the exception upward?

Comment: I'd go for the last one. As it has the least chance of creating weird issues. However, I'd not ever throw (then again, I never used C++ Exceptions, just Python and Java). 

And I've used it in the Better-to-Ask-Forgiveness kind of way.

Comment: Is this for exceptions which you throw, or for exceptions which are thrown by the STL?

Comment: @ChrisW - It's some exception inherited from `std::exception` (mostly `std::runtime_error`).

Comment: I'd use Boost.Exception (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html), which allows you add information in the exception. In particular, see the "Nesting Exception" last paragraph of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/exception/doc/exception_ptr.html.

Comment: @ddevienne - Thank you. Interesting idea. I'll try to implement this approach myself. Unfortunately, I do not know `Boost.Exceptions` enough. May be somebody else can implement it.

Answer (score 7):

You can re-throw an exception:

```
int main() {
    ...   
    try {
        ...
        try
        {
            foo();
        }
        catch(std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << "Fatal error: " << e.what() << std::endl;

            throw; // re-throw the exception.
                   // or you could throw a different exception.
        }
        ...   
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Fatal error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return;   
    }
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of ...

- Catching the exception
- Printing a message
- Returning gracefully (from main)

... you can ...

- Not catch the exception
- Print a stack trace
- Abort execution

I'm not sure you can print the type of exception (using the `what()` method) if you do this, but a stack trace tells you not only that it happened inside `foo` but also in which subroutine of `foo`.

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+exception+stack+trace) suggests how to get a stack trace from a C++ exception; for example [this article](http://oroboro.com/stack-trace-on-crash/) looks useful (you'll get more-specific information if you specify a specific O/S in your Google search).

Advantages of this over catching an exception are:

- Don't clutter your code with `catch` statements
- A complete (deep) stack trace may be more useful than just knowing that it happened somewhere inside `foo`

(This may not work: [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443135/how-do-i-find-where-an-exception-was-thrown-in-c#comment2499431_2445569) says that it's implementation-defined whether the stack is unwound before the terminate handler is called.)

---

If you're catching exceptions which you throw yourself, then you can have the best of both worlds (a `catch` and a stack trace): define a type of exception which captures a stack trace in its constructor (when it's thrown), then you can print the stack trace when you catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Here I assume you want to handle exceptions from different fragments/classes inside main and take action accordingly.

You can use Macros to create new Exception and throw the exception to differentiate  exceptions in case you have to differentiate.

```
#define CREATE_EXCEPTION(EXCEPTION_NAME) \
class EXCEPTION_NAME : public std::exception \
{ \
      std::string msg; \
      public: \
       EXCEPTION_NAME(std::string mesg):msg(mesg){} \
       std::string getMessage(){ return msg;}\
       ~EXCEPTION_NAME()throw (){}\
}; 
#define CATCH_THROW_EXCEPTION(CATCH_EXCEPTION,THROW_EXCEPTION)    \
     catch (CATCH_EXCEPTION &e) { \
    std::cout << "Foo failed. The reason is:" << std::endl; \
    throw THROW_EXCEPTION(e.what()); \
    }

CREATE_EXCEPTION(Foo_Exception);
void foo()
{
  try {
      ..
    }
    CATCH_THROW_EXCEPTION(std::exception,FOO_EXCEPTION) 
  }
}

int main() {
  ...
  try {
    ...
    foo();
    ...
  } 
  catch (Foo_Exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Fatal error:"<< e.getMessage() << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Fatal error: "<< e.what() << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```